# bind key to navigate results

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a input and i am fetching results using ajax this is the simplified code that looks like this

```
<input placeholder="search here" id="search"></input>
<div id="searchResults">
     <a href="link">search result 1</a>
     <a href="link">search result 2</a>
</div>
```

So what i want is when somebody searches something and the results that are being showed in the next div can be navigated via arrow keys without moving the mouse or using the tab key.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show some code that you tried and did not work, this is not a coding service...

Comment: im not saying that you should code and i dont think i am the first one that needs to do it if you would have just shared something that i could read to use it would have been helpfull

Comment: Right, you are not the first one, so ask on Google or search for an existing question first. Research, first and then ask if you cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example. Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/HJGFG/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $(document).keyup(function (e) 
     {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
         if (code == 38) {
             $("#searchResults a").css("background-color","#fff");
            $("#searchResults a").prev().css("background-color","yellow");
         } 
         else if (code == 40) 
         {
             $("#searchResults a").css("background-color","#fff");
            $("#searchResults a").next().css("background-color","yellow");
         }
    });

});
```